# how to find current day is weekday or weekends in Python?

Tags: python

Please suggest me on the following.
How to find whether a particular day is weekday or weekend in Python?

Answer (score 184, accepted):

You can use the [`.weekday()` method of a `datetime.date` object](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.weekday)

```
import datetime

weekno = datetime.datetime.today().weekday()

if weekno < 5:
    print "Weekday"
else:  # 5 Sat, 6 Sun
    print "Weekend"
```

Answer (score 28):

Use the `date.weekday()` method. Digits 0-6 represent the consecutive days of the week, starting from Monday.