# Finding out whether a date is a weekend or weekday

Tags: python, datetime, weekday

I have made this code that should return whether a specific date is a weekend or a weekday but always returns weekday.
What's wrong?
I am new to python so any help would be appreciated :)

```
import datetime
def sunday_saturday_definer():
date_for_checking = datetime.datetime(day = 10, month= 12, year= 2019)
if date_for_checking.weekday == 5:
    print("weekend")
elif date_for_checking.weekday == 6:
    print("weekend")
else:
    print("Weekday")
sunday_saturday_definer()
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29384696/how-to-find-current-day-is-weekday-or-weekends-in-python

Comment: 1. It's always the same date. 2. Weekday is a *method*.

Comment: Did you research here for `date`+ `weekday`+`python`? This question answers it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9847213/how-do-i-get-the-day-of-week-given-a-date

Comment: What did you expect? The date `2019-12-10` is a _Tuesday_, hence `weekday` is expected in this case 

Answer (score 1):

use `date_for_checking.weekday()`

Answer (score 1):

Your code evaluating `date_for_checking.weekday` returns the *reference to the function*, because you missed the parentheses.

If you want to *call the function* use **parentheses**:

```
is_weekend = date_for_checking.weekday() in [5,6]
is_weekday = date_for_checking.weekday() in range(0,5)
```

See the [docs for `date.weekday()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.weekday):

> Return the day of the week as an integer, where Monday is 0 and Sunday is 6. For example, `date(2002, 12, 4).weekday() == 2`, a Wednesday. See also `isoweekday()`.